# Automatically screenshot capture of Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

Is it possible to have a automatic screenshot capture of Zabbix CPU & Memory Graph

Is there any 3rd party tool which can be implemented with Zabbix for capturing the screenshot.

As a status mail it should be delivered via On daily bases morning and evening 8.00 clock

My exact aim is to collect daily status from Zabbix instead of creating any script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images (which are plain PNG) can be grabbed with scripts - and there are scripts that do so. You finish your question with "instead of creating any script", but I assume that a script that collects data from Zabbix (instead of doing its own data collection) would be acceptable. A couple of community efforts to generate reports:

- [Zabbix PDF report generaton](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24998)
- [Zabbix Extras](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=44411)

Note that if you really want to achieve this without any scripts, that is not possible.